# Why do I get different length of array of outputed elements depending on the position of elements of iterating array?

Tags: python-3.x, set, html-parsing, python-requests

So, the purpose of this code is to provide the list of URLs on the page, but I found out that **the amount of outputed URLs** depends on the position of elements in the array which is used while iterating, i.e. **params = ["src", "href"]**

The code contains the working programs with imported **Requests** library, used requests.get(), response.text, and such structures as lists and loops.
To copy the code, use **Expand Snippet** button.

---

**Questions:**

1. Why do I get *8 urls* when I use "src" on the 0-s position in the params array
   and *136 urls* when I use "href" on the 0-s position in the params array, see:

[image: "href" on the 1st position]

[image: "src" on the 1st position]

2. How is it possible to obtain all elements (src and href) in the array all_urls?

```html
import requests


domain = "https://www.python.org/"


response = requests.get(domain)
page = response.text
all_urls = set()
params = ["src", "href"]


def getURL(page, param):

    start_link = page.find(param)
    if start_link == -1:
        return None, 0
    start_quote = page.find('"', start_link)
    end_quote = page.find('"', start_quote + 1)
    url = page[start_quote + 1: end_quote]
    return url, end_quote

for param in params:

    while True:
        url, n = getURL(page, param)
        page = page[n:]
        #count += 1
        if url:
            if url.startswith('/') or url.startswith('#!'):
                all_urls.add(domain + url)
            elif url.startswith('http'):
                all_urls.add(url)
            else:
                continue
        else:
            break


print("all urls length:", len(all_urls))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1- This happens because you are consuming your `page` variable inside the loop

```
url, n = getURL(page, param)
page = page[n:] // this one here
```

This just slices the page string after each iteration and reassigns it to the same variable, hence you loose a chunk on each iteration. When you get to the last `src` or `href` you are probably already at the end of the document.

2- A very quick fix for your code would be to reset the `page` for each new `param`:

```
for param in params:
    page = response.text
    while True:
        url, n = getURL(page, param)
        page = page[n:]
        ....
```

---

### **However**

There is a far better way to handle `HTML`. Why don't you just use a `HTML Parser` for this task?

For example you could use [BeautifulSoup4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), for example: *(not optimal code and not tested, just for a fast demonstration)*

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("https://www.python.org/")
page = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

all_urls = list()

elements = page.find_all(lambda tag: tag.has_attr('src') or tag.has_attr('href'))

for elem in elements:
    if elem.has_attr('src'):
        all_urls.append(elem['src'])
    elif elem.has_attr('href'):
        all_urls.append(elem['href'])

print("all urls with dups length:", len(all_urls))
print("all urls w/o dups length:", len(set(all_urls)))
```

Comment: I also proposed to use Beautiful Soap, but it was considered that the code would be to "heavy" and not so quick. I think we'll test it and find out what is better.

Comment: The nice thing about Beautiful Soup is the ability to use different parser under the hood. You can read about it here: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser